# iOS UIWebView flicker issue

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and a swipe gesture in the same screen. When I'm swiping, I am reloading the webview, because if I don't, the call to js is not being made.

The reload works only once, **I am unable to swipe again**.

When I removed `[self.webview reload]`swiping is done fine, but the UIWebView keeps flickering. It just jumps up everytime!
I need to make a call to js everytime I swipe.

I tried these:

**Method 1:**

```
when loading webview:
 self.webview.alpha = 0;

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];    
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.30];    
    self.webview.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [self.webview setOpaque:NO];
    self.webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  }
```

**Method 3:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.webview loadHTMLString:@"<html><body style=\"background-color:black;\"></body></html>" baseURL:nil];    

    [self performSelector:@selector(loadWebview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
-(void)loadWebview {

    self.webview.delegate = self;
    self.webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    self.webview.scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webview];
    pathToHtml = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypath" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* appHtml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToHtml encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToHtml];

    [self.webview loadHTMLString:appHtml baseURL:baseURL]; 
}
```

Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I had this in my `webViewDidFinishLoad` :

```
  //Make the page fit to view. THIS IS BAD
    CGRect webviewBound = self. webview.bounds;
    webviewBound.size.height = self. webview.scrollView.contentSize.height;
    self. webview.bounds = webviewBound;
```

So I removed that and added:

```
  [self.webview.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(self.webview.frame.size.width, self.webview.scrollView.contentSize.height)];
    self.webview.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

And I added this in `viewDidLoad` because I had grey background:

```
//Removes the shadow from the webview i.e., "grey background"
if ([[self.webview subviews] count] > 0)
{
    for (UIView* shadowView in [[[self.webview subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
    {
        [shadowView setHidden:YES];
    }

    // unhide the last view so it is visible again because it has the content
    [[[[[self.webview subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] lastObject] setHidden:NO];
}
```